# Macro that maps a number to pifont ding character

Tags: macros, pifont

With `pifont`, the darkened circled number starts from 182.

[image]

I made a macro that maps `\dcircle{1}` to `\ding{182}` as follows.

```
\newcommand{\dcircle}[1]{\ding{181 + #1}}
```

However, `\dcircle{1}` returns the characters that I don't expect:

[image]

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to evaluate the numeric expression; `\numexpr` provides this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\dcircle}[1]{\ding{\numexpr181 + #1}}
\begin{document}

\ding{182}\ \dcircle{1}
\end{document}
```

Note that this performs no end-of-sequence checking.